# Why do particles of an interstellar cloud reach the center simultaneously?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, symmetry, astrophysics

A spherical cloud in interstellar space is made of point matter particles. The cloud's mass is evenly distributed with density $\rho$. The particles start to attract one another (due to gravitational force), which brings about the shrinkage of the cloud. Each particle has a velocity toward the center of spherical cloud. My question is: Why do all the particles of that cloud reach the center simultaneously?

Comment: The collapse of a pressureless cloud purely under Newtonian gravity is actually a difficult problem. https://www.hrpub.org/download/20190530/UJME4-15113068.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Before why, ask if.

Point-like particles in a point-like volume mutually collide and therefore do not reach the center simultaneously, even in this oversimplified scenario. It is analogical as the paradox of "unstoppable force meeting unmovable object".

But, putting that aside, gravitation force in such a scenario is  proportional to the radius, leading to velocities proportional to radius.

In reality, due variable density,  interparticle forces and total cloud angular momentum, it is far from being possible.